# Team Foundation Server (TFS) and mass edits

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

In Visual Studio 2008 I did a find and replace on certain text in config files in a folder under TFS control.  The find and replace replaced text in 75 config files.

A message box displayed saying the files were write protected and asked me something like if I wanted to "Save As..." or "Overwrite".  I selected Overwrite on all of them.

I see that all the files were changed but they were not checked out of TFS.  Usually when I start editing a file it automatically gets checked out and shown as pending.  However, none are pending except the one in the solution I am currently in.

How can I check in all the other 74 files in mass with one description and not have to do each one, one at a time?

Thanks!

Comment: Get the TFS power tools and run `tfpt online /diff`.

Comment: Edward, that looks good, but when I run it I get "Unable to determine the workspace".  I can find no information as to what this means or how to resolve it.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, if you're in VS2008 you will need the TFS 2008 power tools.

Comment: Awesome! Worked great!  If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as the answer to this question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server Power Tools which can be found here:

[Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15836)

1) Make changes to your files.

2) Open a command prompt where the files exist.

3) Run the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools\TFPT.exe" online /diff
```

4) In the windows that opens sort so that you can see Edited files.

5) Select the files that were changed and un-select everything else.

6) Change state to Pending.

7) Go to Visual Studio and check in Pending files.